# vl53l0x v2 выдает странные значения

Tags: c++, arduino

Сначала я подключил датчик по схеме из интернета.
vin - 5в
gnd - gnd
scl - A5
sda - A4
Загрузил в arduino этот код:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <VL53L0X.h>

VL53L0X sensor;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();

  sensor.setTimeout(500);
  sensor.init();

}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println(sensor.readRangeContinuousMillimeters());
}
```

Все работало некоторое время. Но потом датчик начал постоянно выдавать 65535. Я подумал, что что-то не так с адресом и запустил i2c scanner, он показал 0x29, насколько я знаю так и должно быть. Я пытался как-то менять программу, но ничего не получилось. Arduino продолжает выводить в порт 65535.

Comment: `Arduino продолжает выводить в порт 65535` - причем тут порт? 65535 это максимальное значение двухбайтного беззнакового числа. То есть, датчик зашкаливает - из-за физической неисправности или неправильного подключения. Может быть, ему надо установить какие-то параметры, смотрите документацию.

Comment: А может быть, это его способ показать бесконечное расстояние, если он ничего не находит.

Comment: дело в том, что я пытаюсь получить с него расстояние, но он в любом случае выводит 65535, даже если на его пути стоит объект или еще что-то. Подключение правильное. Если датчик физически не исправен, то i2c scanner не нашел бы его

Comment: другого датчика у меня нет. К другому устройству подключал, это были другаая arduino uno и arduino nano. Везде одно и тоже. Еще забыл добавить. Когда это началось, датчик выдвал 8190 или 65535, но потом после перезагрузки или переподключения он показывал нормальные значения

Comment: я как-то смог решить эту проблему. Я переподключил датчик и загрузил этот код:                           `#include <Wire.h>
#include <VL53L0X.h>

VL53L0X sensor;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();

  sensor.setTimeout(500);
  if (!sensor.init())
  {
    Serial.println("Не удалось обнаружить и инициализировать датчик!");
    while (1) {}
  }
  sensor.setMeasurementTimingBudget(100000);

}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print(sensor.readRangeSingleMillimeters());
  Serial.println();
}`

Comment: vin - это не 5 вольт, это напряжение блока питания.

Comment: Итак. Все оказалось гораздо проще. Моя arduino не могла выдать достаточно напряжения для питания всех устройств. Пришлось брать питание с внешенго источника